# How to speed up this DP?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to solve [this problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/SPIDY2/) from codechef and created a top-down DP solution that utilises memoization. The following is the code for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> height;
vector<int> memo;

int jump(int i)
{
    if(memo[i] != -1)
        return memo[i];
    else
    {
        int min = 987654321, res;
        for(int j = (i - 1);j >= 0;j--)
        {
            if(!(height[i]-height[j] == 0) && !(height[i]-height[j] & (height[i]-height[j] - 1)))
            {
                res = jump(j) + height[i]-height[j];
                if(res < min)
                    min= res;
            }
        }
        memo[i] = min;
        return min;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    height.resize(n, 0);
    memo.resize(n, -1);
    memo[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &height[i]);
    }
    int ans = jump(n-1);
    printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

The time limit for the problem is 1 second and I saw a number of solutions doing nearly the same thing(int bottom up DP) and passing... But I read that bottom-up DP and top-down DP are exactly the same in terms of time complexity, and sometimes, in few cases, better. But, this seems to violate the law...

I feel I'm not memoizing the solutions correctly, and or, am defining the subproblems in an in-efficient way. Can someone help me here ?

Comment: Theoretical time complexity does not always correspond with actual runtime in practice on a real computer.  Just something to consider.

Comment: You are using recursion! That turns a simple `n log n` problem into what looks like `n^2 log n` or worse. Also you should generate those powers of two directly, instead of checking for each distance whether it is a power of two. And the cost is `abs(height[i] - height[j])`, not `height[i] - height[j`. And a jump from `j` to `i` is possible if `i-j` is a power of 2, not if `height[i]-height[j]` is. I suggest you look at the leading solutions for hints.